# Python, why is this lambda function not correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

flight_data is dataframe in panda:

```
  for c in flight_data.columns:
      if ('Delay' in c):
          flight_data[c].fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

How do I do this in 1 line using lambda function?

```
map(lambda c: flight_data[c].fillna(0, inplace = True), list(filter(lambda c : 'Delay' in c, flight_data.columns)))
```

Why aren't these two equivalent?

When printing out the data, NaN is not replaced by 0.

Comment: Don't do this. You aren't interested in the iterable that `map` produces, only the side effect of calling the `fillna` method on each element of the original sequence. Keep the `for` loop as it is.

Comment: In Python 3, the function defined by your lambda expression isn't called until you actually iterate over the return value of `map`; until then, you just have a bunch of method calls waiting to happen.

Comment: @chepner +1, thank you, but can you clarify your second comment please, the map does have return value, which are result dataframe of fillna operations right? Do you mean I need to do "for x in map" ..?

Comment: Is there a way to do above operation (do fillna for column names that contain 'Delay') in 1 line? perhaps by using apply? I tried but failed on using apply, as each function applies to row/column data only.

Comment: `map` effectively just creates a wrapper around the original iterable. When you retrieve an element from it, you pull an element from the original "through" the function being mapped over it. Only then does the function actually get called. By contrast, in Python 2, `map` immediately called the function on each element of the iterable, return a list of the return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't use `lambda`

`lambda` only obfuscates logic here. Just specify in-scope columns and use `fillna` directly:

```
cols = df.filter(like='Delay').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(0)
```

> How do I do this in 1 line using lambda function?

But to answer your question, you can do this *without* relying on side-effects of `map` or a list comprehension:

```
df = df.assign(**df.pipe(lambda x: {c: x[c].fillna(0) for c in x.filter(like='Delay')}))
```